# Удар ножом. Можно ножом ударить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Так стали говорить, кажется, совсем недавно. Теперь и писать. В словарях по этому поводу всё по-старому: УДАР как толчок, шок, атака, с лёту, в штангу, апокалиптический, ядерный и т. д. — упоминается десятки раз; НОЖ как инструмент и орудие для резания, а ещё ножи специальные, национальные, — сотни раз. Главное, удар и нож в одной статье не встречаются.

И вот: "кто-то ударил кого-то ножом в живот". Ежели по отдельности (ударил в живот; ножом в живот), то понятно. Но вместе...

Comment: Кто смог, тот высказался, кажется. Спасибо. Мнение такое: "нештатными" предметами бить можно - от орудия пролетариата до микроскопа, но нож, придуманный и созданный человеком для резания и тёски (не экзоты по 50 см длиной и более, они для рубки), — изделие специальное, тонкое, ближе к микроскопу. Соседи ножа в этом строю — ножницы, а по другую сторону, ближе к булыжнику, находится топор. Тоже лезвие, тоже обух, и рукоять. И, хотя обухом ножа можно вогнать гвоздь в стену, но это лишь в теории: его функция здесь совсем не ударная.

Answer (score 4):

Такое употребление вполне корректно. Обратите внимание на значение в словаре. Удар - это не просто толчок, а толчок производимый ***кем-, чем-л. с размаху;*** ***резкое столкновение чего-л. движущегося с кем-, чем-л. движущимся или неподвижным.***

У. кулаком, палкой. При этом орудие может быть любым.

Comment: Когда столкновение чего-либо приводит к проникновению внутрь, то говорят, что оно врезается. У ножа, действительно, есть части без режущих кромок. Если применять нож нетрадиционным способом, тогда живот не сильно пострадает при ударе. Вы правы: что б ударить, надо держать нож за лезвие.

Answer (score 3):

Ножом вполне можно ударить, причем даже несколькими способами: удар плашмя, колющий, режущий, если нож большой, возможен еще и рубящий. Сочетание *удар ножом* встречается у Достоевского, Булгакова, Шаламова и др., так что никаких ограничений для употребления этого словосочетания не вижу.

Comment: Для всех этих вариаций "ударов" есть соответствующие им "заколол, пырнул, зарезал, полоснул". Следовательно, тот, кто сообщил нам, что "кто-то ударил кого-то ножом в живот", не вполне владел информацией? Он только слышал звон? Относительно удара (ножом) плашмя. Представить его в чистоте можно лишь как случайную отмашку, да он к нашему случаю с животом и не относится: тогда было бы "по животу". Что до "рубящего", то вряд ли сочетание "зарубил ножом" встретится у Достоевского, Булгакова, Шаламова.

Comment: @shampar, ударить ножом не одно и тоже, что зарезать или заколоть, так как не факт, что действие завершено и кто-либо погиб. "Пырнуть" же - это не литературное слово. Да и зачем такие сложности? Человек нанес удар ножом, а что он при этом намеревался сделать черт его знает.

Answer (score 3):

[Национальный корпус русского языка](http://ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html) очень удобен когда нужно проверить как давно употребляется выражение. Вот например цитаты начала 19 века:

> Каждое слово его было ударом ножа в грудь Софии Алексеевны; я видел, как глаза ее разгорались, как грудь ее волновалась от досады. *[И. И. Лажечников. Последний Новик (1833)]*
>
> она сама была ранена в шею ударом ножа или косы, и лапы ее были обожжены, видно, тогда, когда она вместе с нами выскочила из пожара. *[О. М. Сомов. Вывеска (1827)]*

И таких примеров там [достаточно много](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%E4%E0%F0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%ED%EE%E6&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=15).

Comment: Удар как эмоциональная вспышка, нож и грудь как мощные мазки в этой картине маслом. Никто никого не режет по живому. Опять же не вопрос: существует ли удар ножа. Нож может выпасть из рук и заехать коту в лоб. Можно ли ножом ударить?

Comment: Меня тоже удивило наблюдение, что так стали говорить недавно. Обоснование возможности так говорить держится больше не на определении понятия удара, а на длительной практике употребления такого выражения - другие глаголы (пырнуть, зарезать, заколоть и пр.) имеют более узкий смысл, не для всякой ситуации подходящий.